# How to select all markers in certain radius from tapped point on HERE map

Tags: android, geolocation, geometry, here-api

I am using HERE map Android SDK.  I have subscribed to `OnGestureListener` as follows. `onMapObjectsSelected` method returns only those markers which are actually clicked. I want to mark near by markers (within radius) SELECTED from `onTapEvent`.

```
mapFragment.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(mlistener);

MapGesture.OnGestureListener mlistener =
    new MapGesture.OnGestureListener.OnGestureListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTapEvent(PointF pointF) {
        int radius = 500; // 500 meter                    
        // How can I select all available markers within 500 mtr radius
        // from point PointF.
        return super.onTapEvent(pointF);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMapObjectsSelected(List<ViewObject> objects) {
        // Selected markers should be auto listed within objects list
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Map#getSelectedObject](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-map.html#topic-apiref__getselectedobjects-viewrect) with a view rect. The viewrect should be computed as the minimal bounding square for your circle of some radius in meters. After that, you can filter the results to prune out any objects returned within the selected object rectangle that is greater than the required distance.

Comment: Thanks @David for your reply. This will give me list of objects as required, but how do i mark them selected so that I will get same set of objects in "onMapObjectsSelected" event ?

Comment: What do you mean as "selected" This will return the set of objects so you can pro grammatically do something with them. onMapObjectSelected is only fired when the user touches the screen, and it is based on a small touch selection.

Comment: Ok, that means onMapObjectSelected can be fired only with set of objects which are selected via user touch not with custom modified list. Anyway, your solution make sense and will work. thanks.

Comment: That is correct, it will only fire based on user input.